# How to execute code after blazor page has loaded

Tags: c#, blazor

So I am trying to execute a method when the page has loaded. The `OnAfterRender()` override method is too early in my case. the method I am trying to do is in my `@code{}` block of the razor page.

I basically want to execute getAvailablePrinters when the page is loaded.

as requested my code below:

```cs
@code {
    private List<string> Printers;

    private List<string> LayoutTypes;

    private void sendPrint()

    private async Task getAvailablePrinters()
    {
        //get layouts
        Layouts = new List<Layout>();
        AvailablePrintersRepository availablePrintersRepository = new AvailablePrintersRepository();
        try
        {
            Layouts = await availablePrintersRepository.getAvailablePrintersAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //show message
        }

        //sort printers & layouts
        Printers = new List<string>();
        LayoutTypes = new List<string>();

        foreach (Layout layout in Layouts)
        {
            foreach (string printer in layout.Printers)
            {
                if (!Printers.Contains(printer))
                {
                    Printers.Add(printer);
                }
            }

            if (!LayoutTypes.Contains(layout.Type))
            {
                LayoutTypes.Add(layout.Type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as too early. `OnAfterRenderAsync and OnAfterRender are called after a component has finished rendering. Element and component references are populated at this point. ` Describe your problem in details, not what you think why <something> happens not in the right time. What is <something>?

Comment: @AccessDenied I want to send a request to another API to get back data i need to display to the user. i now have a button to do it but i want to get the data after the page has loaded so the user doesn't have to press the button each time

Comment: Provide the code that you already have.

Comment: Why do you think it's too early?

Comment: Because the method isn't finished when the page has loaded so that is why I want to do it after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 3):

> @AccessDenied I want to send a request to another API to get back data i need to display to the user. i now have a button to do it but i want to get the data after the page has loaded so the user doesn't have to press the button each time

--

> Because the method isn't finished when the page has loaded so that is why I want to do it after the page has loaded

So you believe that the OnAfterRenderAsync and OnAfterRender are called too early  in the pipeline, and thus are not fit for the Web Api call you want to do in order to retrieve data, right ?

You are wrong, they are, in my opinion too late for this enterprise, and you should use the OnInitializedAsync life cycle method to execute the HTTP request.
Please see the VS template how a Web Api is made to populate the ForeCast objects
in the FetchData page.

You should try code in various situations to understand how the initialization process works, and see that your ideas or perceptions are wrong. Understand this: You should retrieve your data before your page is rendered, not after it is being rendered. OnAfterRender(Async) may be used to execute code that otherwise it's too early to execute. It is most often used to initialize JS objects.

Hope this helps...